# C compiler gcc not found while installing passenger and nginx

Tags: nginx, gcc, centos, sh, passenger

I'm trying to install Passenger and Nginx on my VPS.

I followed [these instructions](http://library.linode.com/frameworks/ruby-on-rails-nginx/centos-5) and replaced all links of all sources to the current version.

But when i ran the Phusion Passenger installer for Nginx, something with gcc compiler went wrong:

```
Compiling and installing Nginx...
# sh ./configure --prefix='/opt/nginx' --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-cc-opt='-Wno-error' --add-module='/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.17/ext/nginx'
checking for OS
 + Linux 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 x86_64
checking for C compiler ... not found

./configure: error: C compiler gcc is not found
```

What should I do?

*OBS: My VPS works with CentOS 6.2 x64*

Comment: Have you installed the CentOS package that contains gcc? If not, install that, it should fix the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Did you really run `yum install zlib-devel wget openssl-devel pcre pcre-devel make gcc gcc-c++ curl-devel`?

Comment: Yes I installed the gcc package and ran `yum install zlib-devel wget openssl-devel pcre pcre-devel make gcc gcc-c++ curl-devel`

Comment: Look I ran `gcc -v`and got
`Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC)`

Comment: @EduardoLeal: There is a remote possibility that the configure script is checking some location for existence of gcc while it is installed at some other location. For example: /usr/bin vs /usr/local/bin. This may be an issue of incompatibility between the packages vs the OS version.

Comment: So I should reinstall the packages in other location or specify the current path location?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you do have gcc installed, the problem stems from /tmp being mounted as noexec. The error doesn't exactly help, but if you remount /tmp as exec you can install passenger properly.

```
mount -o remount,rw,exec,nosuid /tmp
```

Comment: That worked. However, redmine doesn't seem to be working since I get an 403 forbidden error. In nginx logs I found `nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "passenger_enabled" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site:33`

Comment: That sounds like you didn't install Nginx with the passenger module. You can do `nginx -V` list the compiled flags. Make sure passenger is listed there. Also make sure `passenger_enabled on;` is listed inside the `server` block.

Answer (score 14):

Have the same problem and the following commands solve it; (on ubuntu server)

```
sudo apt-get install linux-kernel-headers
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Answer (score 8):

Got the same error. Just installed gcc and it started working:

> yum install gcc

Comment: Got the same problem on Amazon Linux AMI and this worked!

Answer (score 6):

same problem here and I found out that I am not able to run command as root
has to use

```
 sudo
```

and it worked like charm

Answer (score 4):

Be sure that you sudo, if applicable.

Example:

```
sudo ./configure ...
```

Answer (score 1):

One quick hack (I struggled a lot with it and finally install pre-built) is to install the pre-built package of Nginx rather than compiling it from source.

For RHEL/CentOS create the file named /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo with the following contents:

```
[nginx]
name=nginx repo
baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/OS/OSRELEASE/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

In above `baseurl` replace “OS” with “centos” and “OSRELEASE” with “6”.

Finally execute `yum install nginx`

Reference https://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#stable