# Error installing Phusion Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, rvm, passenger

I've been trying to install Phusion Passenger on my Centos VPS hosting a rails 3 app but I keep getting the following error:

```
Installing Phusion Passenger Standalone...
[********************************             ] Preparing Nginx... \           
checking for OS
 + Linux 2.6.18-238.12.1.el5xen x86_64
checking for C compiler ... found but is not working

./configure: error: C compiler gcc is not found
```

I've followed all the instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770501/c-compiler-gcc-not-found-while-installing-passenger-and-nginx/12998464#12998464) but it doesn't seem to make any difference. Among other things I've tried is downloading the nginx-1.2.3 source and compiling them manually using a different source directory and they compile and install correctly. But when I try to run passenger start from my rails app, it will trigger the installation all over again. Running nginx -v does show it as installed. Any help would be appreciated ! I'm running Ruby 1.9.2.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously a `gcc` compiler is missing. You can check it in console by typing:

```
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc  # expected response
```

If you are running Debian/Ubuntu, this should solve it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc make autoconf libc-dev
```

on Centos/RedHat/Fedora probably this should work:

```
$ sudo yum install gcc make autoconf
```